# requires_grad of params is True even with torch.no_grad()

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I am experiencing a strange problem with PyTorch today.

When checking network parameters in the `with` scope, I am expecting `requires_grad` to be `False`, but apparently this is not the case unless I explicitly set all params myself.

**Code**

Link to Net -> [Gist](https://gist.github.com/rexlow/90603a0a68c187a4baedb89fe319753f)

```
net = InceptionResnetV2()

with torch.no_grad():

    for name, param in net.named_parameters():
        print("{} {}".format(name, param.requires_grad))
```

The above code will tell me all the params are still requiring grad, unless I explicitly specify `param.requires_grad = False`.

My `torch` version: `1.0.1.post2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`torch.no_grad()` will disable gradient information for the *results* of operations involving tensors that have their `requires_grad` set to `True`. So consider the following:

```
import torch

net = torch.nn.Linear(4, 3)

input_t = torch.randn(4)

with torch.no_grad():

    for name, param in net.named_parameters():
        print("{} {}".format(name, param.requires_grad))

    out = net(input_t)

    print('Output: {}'.format(out))

    print('Output requires gradient: {}'.format(out.requires_grad))
    print('Gradient function: {}'.format(out.grad_fn))
```

This prints

```
weight True
bias True
Output: tensor([-0.3311,  1.8643,  0.2933])
Output requires gradient: False
Gradient function: None
```

If you remove `with torch.no_grad()`, you get

```
weight True
bias True
Output: tensor([ 0.5776, -0.5493, -0.9229], grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)
Output requires gradient: True
Gradient function: <AddBackward0 object at 0x7febe41e3240>
```

Note that in both cases the module parameters have `requires_grad` set to `True`, but in the first case the `out` tensor doesn't have a gradient function associated with it whereas it does in the second case.

Comment: Your answer makes sense. However it does no different, with or without the `with` scope in my machine. Please have a look at the screenshot in the updated post.

Comment: But you are computing `pred` _before_ `with torch.no_grad()`. Try to move `pred = self.net.forward(t)` inside the `with` block.

Comment: Thanks! I understand the difference now.

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Comment: But still the parameters have `requires_grade=True`. How we save memory then during inference if we have something like `with torch.no_grad(): # code for prediction`.